# grade import class from project a-> project b in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a problem like this.

Project structure:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T17Kr.png)

I have a Base.java class in test1 then I want extends it in my BaseDao.java class in test2 so I have config in setting.gradle and build.gradle in test2 like this

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':test1')
    implementation project(path: ':test1', configuration: 'default')
    testImplementation project(path: ':test1', configuration: 'default')

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.4.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

setting.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'test2'

include(":test1")
project(":test1").projectDir = new File("../test1")
```

and then I extends Base like this

```
import com.example.test1.base.Base;

public abstract class BaseDao extends Base { 
    
}
```

when I run gradle build in test2, it fail

```
error: package com.example.test1.base does not exist
```

what I was wrong

sorry for my bad English and question seem so long
thanks so much

Comment: It seems like test1 and test2 are independent Gradle projects that just happen to be under TEST directory. They have no relation to each other. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications_multi_project.html

Comment: yeah I know but I must do like that. tks for your reply <3

Comment: may be an issue with file path resolution - try `project(":test1").projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "../test1")`      Also show the list of tasks run when you do the test2 build

Comment: the same error, the library dependencies in grade.build in test 1 is recognized in test2 but class Base is not. Tks for your idea